# ActionScript errors when Swf embedded into HTML

Tags: flash, actionscript, embed

Hey I am using swf object to embed a swf into a html page. When I compile the swf there are no errors yet when I embed it into a web page i keep getting thrown either one of these two errors the first time the page loads in Safari and Chrome

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference at tracks/loadFlashvars()
        at tracks/init()
        at tracks

SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.

In firefox I get thrown the same errors everytime the page loads. My swf loads other swfs and and they have XML loaders I thought maybe it could be something to do with the base swf not being fully loaded before the code is run so I have been playing around with setTimeout(); to try and make a work around but I am unsure if this is correct or if my embed code is wrong, which you can see below.

```
There is a live version here http://music-shed.org/tracks/
```

Any hints or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really tell what you're trying to do because you haven't shown any AS3 code. However, if you're trying to load files from a remote location you'll need to load a cross domain policy that's held at their end.

```
Security.allowDomain("*");
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://somedomain.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

This might help you out.

EDIT:

Maybe try a new embed code:

```
<object width="300" height="200">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed wmode="transparent" src="/resource/flash/tracks.swf" width="300" height="200"></embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Hi all cross domain stuff is set up correctly. And all loaded swfs are on the same directory. There are no Actionscript errors until I try to embed them into a page and flash player debugger throws errors saying it can't fire my constructor etc

Comment: @Alex Vince Strange.. Try embedding the media differently?

Comment: It is very strange mate I have been struggling with this for a day or so now and I am absolutely baffled. I have tried various ways of embedding the files to no avail. Cheers

Comment: Sorry bud, here's a resource if it helps at all: http://www.actionscripterrors.com/?p=409